# Crypto AES decryption not working in node js API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, encryption, cryptojs

On my website, I have encrypted the object using crypto AES encryption in react frontend.
Now I have to decrypt it at the node JS backend.

I am using the **same key**, **same version of crypto JS package**, **same node version** on both sides.
But the encrypted string at react frontend side is not being decrypted at the node JS backend.

I have used the below code for encryption and decryption.

**Encryption at React frontend side**

```
const pinObj = {
    pin: this.state.pin_number,
};
let ciphertext = crypto.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(pinObj), config.aesSecretkey);
const encryptedText = ciphertext.toString();
```

**Decryption at Node JS backend side**

```
const encryptedText = data['encrypted_pin_number'];
const bytes = crypto.AES.decrypt(encryptedText, config.aesSecretkey);
const decryptedData = bytes.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
const pinObj = JSON.parse(decryptedData);
```

I got blank string in `decryptedData` variable.

Can you please suggest what is the issue and what is the solution for this?

Comment: The code is quite straightforward and doesn't seem to contain bugs.  If both codes are executed in the same environment, the decryption works. You should check if `encryptedText` on the decryption and encryption side are identical. Possibly the problem is in the data transfer. Also the equality of the keys should be checked. It would be best to post sample data (plaintext, password and ciphertext).

Comment: It looks like you are trying to encrypt transport channel between client and server. But https does this for you automatically. There were times when someone would try to invent such encryption prior appearence of "Lets Encrypt" but now you can protect communications between your server and clients for free. Do you really need to encrypt something inside already encrypted communication channel?

Comment: @Topaco yes I have checked, `encryptedText` is identical on both sides and the same key is used on both sides.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny Yes, I am passing PIN number of a User to access a web portal. So my client does not want to pass it in plain form.

Comment: As I said, in the same environment both codes work. You should post an example for the React frontend side code, i.e. the values of `JSON.stringify(pinObj)`, `config.aesSecretKey` and `ciphertext.toString()`.